# how to replace conditional with polymorphism?

Tags: java

i'm resolving Gilded Rose kata in java. I started factoring some code and actually i found myself blocked because i couldn't continue after changing some code with subclasses. So i have a switch case bloc with item.name parameter as shown : 
 this is my item.java

```
  public class Item {

     public String name;

public int sellIn;

public int quality;

Item(String name, int sellIn, int quality) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sellIn = sellIn;
    this.quality = quality;
}

public static Item createItem(String name,int sellIn, int quality) {
    switch (name) {
    case "Aged Brie":
        return new AgedBrie(sellIn,quality);
    case "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert":
        return new BackstagePass(sellIn,quality);
    case "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros":
        return new Sulfuras(sellIn,quality);
           default:
                return new Item(name,sellIn,quality);      
    }
}

protected void doUpdateQuality() {

       if(quality >0) {
            quality = quality - 1;

       }
       sellIn = sellIn - 1; 

       if(sellIn <0) {
           if(quality >0) {
                quality = quality - 1;

           }
       }

}

   @Override
    public String toString() {
    return this.name + ", " + this.sellIn + ", " + this.quality;
    }
    }
```

this is my gildedRose.java

```
    class GildedRose {
Item[] items;

public GildedRose(Item[] items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public void updateQuality() {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        doUpdateQuality(items[i]);
    }
}
     private void doUpdateQuality(Item item) {
    switch (item.name) {
    case "Aged Brie":
            if (item.quality < 50) {
                item.quality = item.quality + 1;

            }

            item.sellIn = item.sellIn - 1;


        if (item.sellIn < 0) {

                if (item.quality < 50) {
                    item.quality = item.quality + 1;
                }
            }
    break;

    case "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert":
                if (item.quality < 50) {
                    item.quality = item.quality + 1;

                        if (item.sellIn < 11) {
                            if (item.quality < 50) {
                                item.quality = item.quality + 1;
                            }
                        }

                        if (item.sellIn < 6) {
                            if (item.quality < 50) {
                                item.quality = item.quality + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                item.sellIn = item.sellIn - 1;      
            if (item.sellIn < 0) {
                 item.quality = 0;
                    }
            break;
    case "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros":
           break;

           default:
               if(item.quality >0) {
                    item.quality = item.quality - 1;

               }
               item.sellIn = item.sellIn - 1;   

               if(item.sellIn <0) {
                   if(item.quality >0) {
                        item.quality = item.quality - 1;

                   }
               }
               break;

    }

    }
```

then i created 3 classes :

```
   public class AgedBrie extends Item {

public AgedBrie(int sellIn, int quality) {
    super("Aged Brie", sellIn, quality);

}


@Override
protected void doUpdateQuality() {
            if (quality < 50) {
                quality = quality + 1;  
            }

        sellIn = sellIn - 1;
        if (sellIn < 0) {

                if (quality < 50) {
                    quality = quality + 1;
                }
            }
  }
   }

   public class BackstagePass extends Item {

public BackstagePass(int sellIn, int quality) {
    super("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", sellIn, quality);
}

@Override
protected void doUpdateQuality() {

    if (quality < 50) {
        quality = quality + 1;

            if (sellIn < 11) {
                if (quality < 50) {
                    quality = quality + 1;
                }
            }

            if (sellIn < 6) {
                if (quality < 50) {
                    quality = quality + 1;
                }
            }
        }

    sellIn = sellIn - 1;        
    if (sellIn < 0) {
     quality = 0;
        }

}

}



    public class Sulfuras extends Item {

public Sulfuras(int sellIn, int quality) {
    super("Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros", sellIn, quality);
}

@Override
protected void doUpdateQuality() {
}

  }
```

Can anyone tell me how to change my code after creating these classes. Save me !

Comment: you'll still need conditions, just to check which is which type

Comment: can you show me how  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, so I could be entirely off-base here. But it seems to me like what you need to do is subclass Item.

First, add a method to Item:

```
public void updateQuality() {
}
```

Then for each of your various types of items, do something like this:

```
public class AgedBrie extends Item {
    // Overrides from Item
    public void updateQuality() {
        // Put the code here for how to update quality for Aged Brie
    }
}
```

Then your updateQuality method inside GildedRose:

```
public void updateQuality() {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].updateQuality();
    }
}
```

This is standard Java polymorphism.